# flask Jinja2 custom template filter crashes

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following filter wich I used successfully in a django-app (just changed the syntax so it works with flask):

```
@blueprint.app_template_filter('process_trans_for_html')
def process_trans_for_html(string):
    def replace_xn(match):
        match = match.group()
        return   x_HK_to_UNI(match[:1]).upper()+x_HK_to_UNI(match[1:3]).lower()
    def replace_xh(match):
        match = match.group()
        return x_HK_to_UNI(match)
    string = re.sub("([a-zA-Z])+_xn", replace_xn, string)
    string = re.sub("([a-zA-Z])+_xh", replace_xh, string)
    return string
```

And it keeps crashing. However if I use the same filter and remove the replace_xh definition and call, it works without any problem:

```
@blueprint.app_template_filter('process_trans_for_html')
def process_trans_for_html(string):
    def replace_xn(match):
        match = match.group()
        return   x_HK_to_UNI(match[:1]).upper()+x_HK_to_UNI(match[1:3]).lower()
    string = re.sub("([a-zA-Z])+_xn", replace_xn, string)
    return string
```

This code works without a problem. Any suggestions on this? Seems quite random and strange to me.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `x_HK_to_UNI`? Perhaps that is causing the error?